# Do all end game builds in Diablo 3 use set items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am using set items now and the difference between with and without is HUGE.

Does all end level game builds in Diablo 3 use set items?

Is it possible without set items?

**Background:**

I used to be a level 180 Diablo 3 barbarian. I used barbarian because I want to leech. I just want to survive and let someone good deal damage. I've been playing for a long time and never got past torment 3. Before RoS I did less than MP 3.

Then, long story short, I tried set items.

Now, I can solo torment X easily.

Comment: Set items have extra bonuses which makes them preferred over regular legendary items sometimes, however legendary items are usually still used as their bonuses might be more appropriate to the build. [Icy Veins has pretty neat builds you can view](http://www.icy-veins.com/d3/solo-end-game-builds), and you can see that they don't always use full sets.

Comment: Oh really. Any end game build that can solo torment x without full sets?

Comment: all builds there uses set items.

Comment: @JimThio I am using a 4-piece Raekor build to speedrun (non just solo, solo fast!) Torment X. While I answer, please take time to edit your question to be more of a question and less of a story :-)

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it's written as a blog post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no.

Granted, class sets are designed to be end-game gear, and are a natural foundation for efficient builds. **Most builds** use full class sets.

But, first, **not all** of them. I can't say for every set, but there is at least a [4-piece Raekor speed build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/20743574719) that sacrifices 6-piece Raekor's bonus for several select legendaries that synergize with 4-piece one.

And second, there is a "no-set set" - **[Legacy of Nightmares](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-wailing-host)** - that greatly boosts your damage and survivability for every Ancient Legendary item, as long as you don't have other set bonuses. This way, (with some dedication to farm all those Ancients) one can truly make their own viable build. Truly optimized LoN builds are often better than set builds (but then you are cornered into using those specific Legendaries the same way you are cornered into using a class set).

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your definition of set pieces.

Every single viable end game build uses some set pieces. Most of them rely on a full six piece class set. However, there are a few builds that don't use the class sets. These, invariably, use the [Legacy of Nightmares](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_Nightmares) ring set, which gives both a damage boost and damage resistance based on how many ancient items you have, but only as long as you don't have any other set BONUSES (you can have other set pieces, but generally you'll want legendaries with beneficial affixes).

The set piece bonuses are just too good to have any competition from ordinary legendaries in the absence of the LoN rings.